# Filtering by tag

Tags: feature-request, tagging, tag-watching

I have seen on a similar site where you can filter by your favorite tags.  It's one thing to have questions with your favorite tags highlighted, and it's another, and much better, to only see questions with your favorite tags.  As of now, you can filter to see one tag by clicking the name in your list of favorite tags.  But what if I quickly want to scan for questions in 10 different categories?  Should I click each one individually?  No, that's terrible.

So, is there a way to add a feature where you can filter based on your favorite tags with a click of the mouse?

Comment: It's not exactly what you want, but you could go to http://stackexchange.com/filters/ and click on "Favorite tags".

Comment: @MartinSleziak I agree on all accounts.  It is a nice thing, but it's also not exactly what I'm looking for.  The problem here is I'd have to go to a different site and login there just to see my favorite tags on this site.  But, it does have the advantage that I could see all the tags I'm interested in on all the sites.  I will probably check this out.  Thanks.

Comment: I think I misread. I am deleting that comment. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I want to be aware whenever an actuarial-science question comes up so I just used your suggestion!  It may be days before one arrives, but I'll get an email update if it does.  Since there was no better answer, and yours is quite useful, you should make it an answer.

Comment: See also: [Newest unanswered questions with my tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20157/newest-unanswered-questions-with-my-tags)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT:**
I found out that there exists a search option `intags:mine` which only returns posts in your favorite tags. So if you [search for](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=intags%3Amine+is%3Aq) `intags:mine is:q` you get list of all questions from your favorite tags. You can then order the search results in the way you wish to (recently active, newest, ...)

This seems to be a way simpler solution that the things I have described below. (I did not know about this search option.) Anyway I am leaving those information here, too, as they may be useful for some users.

---

Per OP's [request](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814/filtering-by-tag#comment22271_3814), I'll post my comment as an answer.

It's not exactly what you want, but you could go to http://stackexchange.com/filters and click on "Favorite tags".

You can also create various other filters there. You can obtain RSS-feed or e-mail notifications from a filter.

That site has one obvious disadvantage that you lose MathJax rendering. One possible solution is use [robjohn's bookmarklets](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html) or something similar to render mathematics.

---

Another possibility would be using in-built search. For example, if you search for `[real-analysis] or [general-topology] or [elementary-set-theory]`, only questions having at least one of these tags are shown. (Here is a [link to this particular search](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis+or+general-topology+or+elementary-set-theory).) You can then choose ordering of the search results (for example choose recently active questions or newest questions).

You can do this for your favorite tags. (Or any set of tags you are interested in.) This means that you have to add several tags manually, but if you plan to look at those tags regularly, you only need to do this once and then bookmark the link to the search or save the link somewhere.

---

There a feature request at meta.SO [Tab for questions that are labeled with favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags), which is tagged [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), but it contains several tips for workarounds.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I think it is closer to what I wanted than I first thought!